# Как перенести из одного {{ form }} объект на другую строку, если у них одни и те же составляющие при CSS без Bootstrap. Django

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

```
{% extends 'home/main.html' %}
{% block main_section %}
<title>Войти</title>
  <div>
    <h2>Авторизация на сайте</h2>
    <form method="POST" class="form">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form }}
      <button>Войти</button>
    </form>
    <hr>
    Забыли пароль? <a href="{% url 'pass-reset' %}">Получите новый</a>
  </div>

{% endblock main_section %}
```

Answer (score 0):

достаточно было `Input{display:block;}`